# Какими способами в Electon можно создать однооконное приложение с полностью динамически меняющимся <body>?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

Новичок в electorn; только построил первое приложение по [этому видеоуроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU). Теперь меня интересует, какие подходы используются при построении приложений, аналогичных мастеру установки программ, когда при каждом нажатии кнопки "Далее" открывается новое окно и предлагается принять следующее решение.

Каждый раз закрывать один `BrowserWindow` и затем открывать новый - не лучшее, на что способны современные технологии, а потому меня интересует, какие возможны варианты реализации однооконного приложения, при котором содержимое окна неоднократно послностью меняется. Другими словами, мы в одном и том же `BrowserWindow` многократно очищаем `<body>` и добавляем туда новое содержимое.

Первый вариант, как я догадываюсь - построение приложение по концепции SPA с использованием React или Vue. Недостаток такого подхода - жесткая связанность между отображением и логикой, что для приложений с пошаговым принятием решений - ужасно. Представьте, что вы редактируете вёрстку отображения, соотстветствующего десятому шагу: одна перезагрузка страницы вследствие изменения разметки или пересборки стилей - и вы снова на странице первого шага (как обстоит дело с маршрутизацией - не знаю, знаю лишь что вместо протокола http, как в web-приложениях, используется простокол file).

Второй вариант, по моей догадке: с использованием нативного JavaScript либо jQuery, а также динамической подгрузки в Webpack, мы опустошаем body и добавляем в него новый контент, подгруженный с помощью webpack. Препроцессор pug и другие позволяют разбивать исходый файл на несколько, так вот: на стадии вёрстки, мы выносим содержимое body в дочерний pug файл и подключаем его в pug-файл с `<html>`, `<head>` и `<body>`, предназначенный для просмотра изменений внешнего вида. Далее, на стадии программирования, мы этот же дочерний файл подгружаем как webpack-module, он автоматически компилируется в `<html>` и мы можем добавить этот html в пустой body.

Какие ещё есть подходы и какие из них Вы можете порекомендовать?

Comment: В чем Вам переход по ссылке не угодил?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, по ссылке на другой HTML-файл? Пока не пробовал. Произойдёт ли при таком переходе закрытие предыдущего окна и открывание нового?

Comment: нет, но в окне полностью перерендерится контент

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, понял. Не могли бы Вы сказать, есть ли какие-нибудь недостатки у этого метода, и если да, то какие решения существуют?